# Amazon RDS Oracle 12.1 Automatic Report Capturing

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, oracle12c

I look after two RDS client sites, both of which are on Oracle 12.1.0.2.v12.

One of the instances has a high CPU load which appears to be caused by the 12.1 "feature" known as Automatic Report Capturing.
[image]

It's a known issue:
https://smarttechways.com/2017/10/11/with-monitor_data-as-select-inst_id-query-found-caused-performance-issue/
https://liups.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Document-2102131.1.pdf

and can ordinarily be disabled by running  `alter system set "_report_capture_cycle_time"=0;`
However, as this is an RDS instance this parameter can't be set.

What's puzzling me is that the other site doesn't appear to have this issue - the specific SQL statement doesn't appear in session history:

```
WITH MONITOR_DATA AS (SELECT INST_ID, KEY, NVL2(PX_QCSID, NULL, STATUS) STATUS, FIRST_REFRESH_TIME, LAST_REFRESH_TIME, REFRESH_COUNT, PROCESS_NAME, SID, SQL_ID, SQL_EXEC_START, SQL_EXEC_ID, DBOP_NAME, DBOP_EXEC_ID, SQL_PLAN_HASH_VALUE, SQL_FULL_PLAN_HASH_VALUE, SESSION_SERIAL#, SQL_TEXT, IS_FULL_SQLTEXT, PX_SERVER#, PX_SERVER_GROUP, PX_SERVER_SET, PX_QCINST_ID, PX_QCSID, CASE WHEN ELAPSED_TIME < (CPU_TIME+ APPLICATION_WAIT_TIME+ CONCURRENCY_WAIT_TIME+ CLUSTER_WAIT_TIME+ USER_IO_WAIT_TIME+ QUEUIN... (truncated)
```

It's as though the "feature" has been disabled on the other site somehow - or conversely, it's somehow been inadvertently enabled at the problematic site.

Any ideas on how this can be disabled?

Comment: you can't change hidden parameters, but you are able to change normal ones, right ? There is a way do disable it, but you have to change a normal parameter for it

Comment: Any idea what the normal parameter for this feature is?

Comment: I post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if you have huge amount of CPU consumption, you will probably get error messages in the alert log of this type

```
Thu Sep 08 04:00:41 2016
Errors in file /app/oracle/diag/rdbms/dbname/dbinstance/trace/dbinstance_m002_14490.trc:
ORA-12850: Could not allocate slaves on all specified instances: 3 needed, 2 allocated
```

If that is the case, indeed disable the feature can only be done by

```
alter system set "_report_capture_cycle_time"=0; /* Default is 60 seconds */
```

Reason:

> If the CPU consumption is significantly high then it is not an
> expected behaviour and could be due to optimizer choosing suboptimal
> plan for the SQL statements. This can happen due to Adaptive
> Optimization, a new feature in 12c.

Therefore, if you can't change the hidden parameter, you might try to disable Adaptive Optimization all together

```
alter system set optimizer_adaptive_features = false scope=both ;
```

As the documentation states

> In 12.1, adaptive optimization as a whole is controlled by the dynamic
> parameter `optimizer_adaptive_features`, which defaults to TRUE. All of
> the features it controls are enabled when `optimizer_features_enable` >=
> 12.1.

Either you upgrade to 19c, or you disable all optimizer adaptive features

[Amazon RDS now supports 19c](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-rds-for-oracle-now-supports-oracle-database-19c/)

Comment: @Huskie69 , any feedback ?

Comment: Not really, as this is an AWS RDS instance, that parameter isn't modifiable.

Comment: you can change parameters in the database using parameter groups. I do it all the time in AWS RDS. You only require to have a parameter group created. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.html

Comment: Thank you.  I have no access to review the parameter groups but will address this with the relevant teams.

Comment: @Huskie69, you're welcome.. good luck

Answer (score 1):

"optimizer_adaptive_features" is not related to "_report_capture_cycle_time" anyhow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).